# Second display black connected through eGPU on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 21.10, external-monitor, gpu-driver

I recently bought an eGPU and a graphics card to go with it. I'm using my main laptop monitor as well as a secondary one hooked up to the back of the eGPU, but the second monitor isn't detected.

My current setup is a R9 290X in a Razer Core X(v2). The second monitor is connected through HDMI, I tried display port and that didn't work either. The Core turns on and [is recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3he2.png) by Ubuntu. The monitor does work as I've tried it through a thunderbolt dock, no problems there. I have plugged a usb keyboard to the eGPU and that also works just fine.

Ive also tried to install the Radeon drivers but I get a problem when running *amdgpu-install*

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rocm-llvm : Depends: libstdc++-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libstdc++-7-dev but it is not installable
             Depends: libgcc-5-dev but it is not installable or
                      libgcc-7-dev but it is not installable
             Recommends: gcc-multilib but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: g++-multilib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: The amdgpu-pro proprietary overlay is neither needed nor available for your release. Whatever the problem is you can be sure it's NOT about drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks for the info